# NHibernate mapping very slow

Tags: nhibernate

I am using nhibernate, to create a collection of immutable domain objects from a legacy oracle DB. some simple lookup using Criteria api take over 60 seconds. If subsequent lookups of the same lookup is very fast usually less than 300ms (100ms in db and rest by nhibernate, ***i dont have 2-level cache or query cache enabled***, all queries do go the DB I checked using nhibernate prof). If however i leave the app idle for a couple of minutes and run the lookup again it takes usualy 50-60 secs,

I have used nhibernate profiler and in every case its clearly showing only at the most 100ms is spend in database, i figure the rest of the time must be taken by nhibernate, I cant understand why ?

Some background info :

1. I am using dynamic-component to map a 20 columns into key value
   pairs.
2. Using nhibernate 2.1
3. i am using dynamic-component in the mapping
4. Once retrieved the data is never modified, in mapping i am
   using mutable=false flag.
5. its a legacy db so i am using a composite
   key in the mapping.
6. I am only retriving around 50 objects in each lookup
7. When I open session I have set FlushMode=Never
8. I also tried stateless session (still have slow performance on initial lookup)
9. I dont not define or use any custom user types in the mapping

I am clearly doing something wrong or missed some thing,  any ideas ?

Comment: almost sounds like it's a remote database? first connection takes long to open and subsequent connections utilize pooling? Does it only take one query to load the collection?

Comment: yep just one query to load the collection. i used nhibernate prof it shows just one query going to the db, also nhibernate prof show the time take by db is at the most 300 ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest downloading a C# performance profiler such as dotTrace. You will be able to quickly get a more accurate understanding of where your performance problem is. I'm pretty sure it is not an NHibernate mapping issue.

Comment: i used dotTrace, its seems to be that the oracle.DataAccess.Client OracleDataReader.Read() method takes 50 secs on some calls, even thoug the actual db query is only 300ms.

Comment: Have you used an SQL profiler, rather than just NHibernate Profiler, to make certain that the query is only taking 300ms?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely not an Nhibernate issue.

1. Use the code below to figure the amount of time it takes to get your data back. (db+network_latency+nhibernate_execution)
2. Once you are positive that there is no APP related latency involved, check the database by looking at the query plan caching and query result caching. The first time the query runs, a cache miss, your db will invest in time-consuming and intensive operations to generate the resultset.
3. If 1 and 2 don't yield any useful information, check your network. Maybe some network pressure is causing heavy latency.
4. As mentioned by JeffreyABecker below, study how your session factories get disposed/created. Find usages of `ISessionFactory.Dispose()` or `configuration.BuildSessionFactory()`. Building ISessionFactory objects is an expensive operation and, typically, you should create them on application start and dispose them on application stop/shutdown. 60s> it is still a sound number for ISessionFactory instantiation.

```
    //Codez

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Begin timing
    stopwatch.Start();

    // Nhibernate specific stuff ONLY in here
    // Depending on your setup, do a session.Flush(); if possible.

    // End Timing
    stopwatch.Stop();

    // Write result - console/log4net/diagnostics.debug/etc
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Comment: I have done 1and 2 as you suggested, without any app related code it took 50 secs on the first call, nhibernate prof consistently shows db is not bottleneck. i will use a .net profiler next

Comment: similar issues reported here https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=836419

Answer (score 1):

How is the lifetime of your SessionFactory being managed?  Is it possible that your SessionFactory is being disposed of after some period of inactivity?